# how to upload and download a zip file to google drive in android?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

My android app, backup the user's data in a zip file. I want to enable the users to upload/download the backup file to their google drive accounts. so, how can I upload/download a zip file to google drive?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [how to download a file using Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads) and how to [upload a file using the API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)? Let me know if this was the kind of information you were looking for or you need anything else :D